# how to get rid of deleted features which are shown in cucumber html report?

Tags: html, testing, automation, cucumber, karate

how to get rid of deleted features which are shown in cucumber html report?

Tried changing the path in runner class still the old features files are shown with new reports.

Comment: works for me. just do a `mvn clean` or `karate -C`. if still having problems, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: its a gradle/cucumber project.. so mvn command is not working and karate -c - it says command not found I am trying this on terminal. Am I doing it correctly ?

Comment: I have no idea about gradle. read the docs, or you are welcome to improve the code of the project or the documentation